# Unable to clear a TextBox using javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm unable to clear the text box when I hit the button with value `C`.

In Opera when I press the number buttons it properly inputs them into the text box but for some reason the `C` button never works! Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pwQpV/9/).

Thanks.

---

*Edit:* I haven't implemented all the functionality yet! Only the number buttons work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename your function to something else and it will work.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pwQpV/11/)

<strike>Now why `clear` was giving a conflict is beyond me, `console.log`ing it returns `undefined` and it's not a keyword AFAIK.</strike>

**edit:** Check Zeta's comment, thanks for the info! `clear` is a deprecated function. [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.clear)

Avoid such generic names in the future to skip some headaches. `=]`

Comment: `clear` is an obsolete function, see http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/obsolete.html#dom-document-clear and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.clear. While it should be only a method of the `document` object it seems like it has polluted the global object in many browser.

Comment: Thanks that worked! I'm coding using notepad++ and neither that nor the Opera dev tool or IE dev tool gave me any conflict errors.

Comment: FF17 doesn't show any error and DreamWeaver CS6 doesn't mark it as a keyword either, but I'm used to seeing problems due to generic naming conflicts so that was my first guess. @AbijeetPatro you can mark this as [accepted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/186879) if your problem is solved (no need to edit the question title). `=]`

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `clear`. Function `clear()` is a reserve word I think

http://www.roseindia.net/javascript/javascript-clear-method.shtml

Answer (score 1):

```
    function findKeyPressed(e)
{
var codeChar=e.keyCode? e.keyCode : e.charCode
    if(codeChar==67)
    {
        document.getElementById('txtBoxId').value="";
    }
}
   <input type="text" onkeyup="findKeyPressed(event); this.select()" />
```